# XSSF can't be resolved to a Type

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have added following Maven dependencies in my project but when i try to read the data from Excel file (.xlsx) it throwing errors of ,

a. XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
b. InvalidFormatException cannot be resolved to a type
c.  Sheet cannot be resolved to a type
d.  Cell cannot be resolved to a type

Can you help me to resolve this error. I have read several blocks and all the necessary dependencies are added but still error pops-up.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>



<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-scratchpad -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
    <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
                 <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                 <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
                 <version>1.0-beta</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1</version>
</dependency>


<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>




public  void readExcel()
        {

            DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
            Date dateExcel  ;
            File fr = new File("C:\\Users\\shankar.manickam\\eclipse-workspace\\PQT Pricing New\\PQTPricing.xlsx");
            Workbook data = null;
            try {
                data = new XSSFWorkbook(fr);
            } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Sheet sheet = data.getSheetAt(0);
            int rowsize = sheet.getLastRowNum();



             Cell c1 = sheet.getRow(0).getCell(1);
             worldArea = c1.getStringCellValue();
             Cell c2 = sheet.getRow(1).getCell(1);
             double lcid1 = c2.getNumericCellValue();
             int lcid2 = (int)Math.round(lcid1);
             lcid = String.valueOf(lcid2);
             Cell c3 =sheet.getRow(2).getCell(1);
             currencyName = c3.getStringCellValue();
             Cell c4 = sheet.getRow(3).getCell(1);
             dateExcel = c4.getDateCellValue();
             date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(dateExcel);
             Cell c5 = sheet.getRow(4).getCell(1);
             countryCode = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(c5);
             Cell c6 = sheet.getRow(5).getCell(1);
             repCode = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(c6);

             System.out.println(worldArea); 
             System.out.println(lcid);  
             System.out.println(currencyName);
             System.out.println(date);
             System.out.println(countryCode);
             System.out.println(repCode);
}

Errors:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    DataFormatter cannot be resolved to a type
    DataFormatter cannot be resolved to a type
    Workbook cannot be resolved to a type
    XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
    InvalidFormatException cannot be resolved to a type
    Sheet cannot be resolved to a type
    Cell cannot be resolved to a type
    Cell cannot be resolved to a type
    Cell cannot be resolved to a type
    Cell cannot be resolved to a type
    Cell cannot be resolved to a type
    Cell cannot be resolved to a type
```

Comment: What Java `import` statements are you using?

Comment: Below are import libraries.


import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

Comment: OK, so what happens when you also decide to import the Apache POI classes too?

Comment: I'm able to import Apache POI classes without any issue. Also in the code i'm able to use methods in POI classes but during run time i'm getting below errors,

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 DataFormatter cannot be resolved to a type
 DataFormatter cannot be resolved to a type
 Workbook cannot be resolved to a type
 XSSFWorkbook cannot be resolved to a type
 InvalidFormatException cannot be resolved to a type
 Sheet cannot be resolved to a type
 Cell cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Edit your code to show the imports, it still seems like you are importing the Apache POI classes wrong

Comment: Can you guide me on how to manually import classes? Sorry i'm new to Java